# How to open a link with target from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url

I have url like this:

```
<a id="preview" ng-href="/preview/{{accountId}}/app/{{app.id}}" target="preview" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-hide="isJobMode">Preview</a>
```

it's part of angular app. and I want to create preview on CTRL+ENTER, I've try:

```
$(document.documentElement || window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('#preview').click();
        }
    }
});
```

but this don't work I need to open a link in new tab and it should be replaced when I do the same when it's already open. I'll probably need to use `window.open` and replace link action with open too, not sure how can I replace window from a script.

Anybody have experience with problem like this or know how to solve it?

Comment: have you read the documentation for click() before using it?

Comment: why are you mixing angular and jquery?

Comment: @DanielA.White angular have bultin jquery lite.

Comment: @jcubic true, but there is likely an angular way to do this.

Comment: @RonniSkansing Yes, Functions like click fire jQuery based event when used without arguments, but this will not fire native click event.

Comment: @jcubic =] then you should read the documentation for the function it actually calls. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html htmlelement.click `For INPUT elements whose type attribute has one of the following values: "button", "checkbox", "radio", "reset", or "submit".` not for <a> or etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click() method simulates a mouse-click on an element.

for more details : **[HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click)**

```
document.getElementById('preview').click();
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for click() before suggesting it?

Comment: The click() method simulates a mouse-click on an element.

Comment: the same would be `$('#preview')[0].click();`

Comment: I have no idea why this would be downvoted, other than people not knowing what they're talking about.

Comment: @Archer: If the OP is hoping to fire a jQuery event, this will fail to so. This will also fail altogether in certain browsers. Also, there's no explanation, just a single line of code. So I think I'll join the club and give it -1.

Comment: @cookiemonster If `$().click()` was't working then this is the correct answer, hence the +1 and disbelief from me.  The answer is in the question, and this is it.

Comment: @Archer: How did you arrive at the conclusion that a different failure makes this code correct? Again, I don't know if he's hoping to trigger a specific jQuery handler or not, but it will fail in some browsers and there's no explanation of the solution given.

Comment: @cookiemonster The biggest clue would be the 2nd comment on this answer.

Comment: @Archer: So you're saying that he tested it in all browsers that he needs to support? I don't get that from that comment. And still the explanation...

Comment: @hutchbat from your own link `However, bubbling of a click event will not cause an <a> element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.` the fact that you can use it, in some browsers (even if the w3 spec's say no), or just simulate it, but that does not make it a good answer. The closest answer is not always good answer.

Comment: @cookiemonster I guess we're just different.  This seems common sense to me.  We disagree is all.

Comment: It appears as though it'll trigger an actual native event, so it should trigger a jQuery handler, so I was wrong about that, but I still there's still more that needs to be said than what's in a single line of code.

Comment: This will generally work, but you should rely on a library's implementation instead of the native `.click` method as shown here: some browsers, and big ones (Android Browser, for example) do **not** support this method and it must be added via polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simulate click on the A element.

```
$('#preview').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

Comment: There is no dispatchEvent in jQuery and `$('a')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))` just return true and do nothing.